# Command Line in Rails App Builder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

If I created a new app builder class like the following:

```
class AppBuilder < Rails::AppBuilder
```

is there a way to write code that will run command line arguments like

```
heroku create
```

when I create a new app with:

```
rails new blog -b app_builder.rb
```

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty simple, in my app builder I wrote:

```
class AppBuilder < Rails::AppBuilder
  def leftovers
    run 'heroku create'
  end
end
```